# ubuntu amp Forbidden

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, permissions

I'm trying to access my site at localhost, but I get:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

My error.log says:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 08:51:51 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 08:51:57 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:51:57 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:52:00 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:52:17 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:54:15 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:54:17 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:55:19 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:55:23 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 08:56:40 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:00:10 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:02:05 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:02:07 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:05:04 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:06:50 2010] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:06:50 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 09:06:57 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun Jun 20 09:08:46 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/index.html
[Sun Jun 20 09:08:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:08:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:47 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:47 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:54 2010] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:54 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:55 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:09:55 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:15:28 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:15:28 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 09:16:51 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:16:51 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 09:16:52 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:16:52 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 20 09:17:04 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/index.html
[Sun Jun 20 09:17:07 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: cannot read directory for multi: /var/www/
[Sun Jun 20 09:17:15 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:17:15 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 20 09:18:38 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/index.html
```

I chowned to myusername:myusername /var and /var/www, chmoded to 711 /var and 751 /var/www, I tried recursive chowning on /var and recursive chmoding on /var/www, but still nothing.

How to access my site?

UPDATE:

var and www are chowned www-data:deltrem, var is chmoded 711, www 751, it still doesn't work :-(

recursive chowning on var (luckyfully) doesn't seem to have worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**/var** should stay chmod 755 and root:root. There is no reason to change /var.

For **/var/www** try:

```
chown -R myusername:www-data /var/www
chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Make sure you keep this permissions when you create files. And you will probaby need to change some files to 775 on those that need to be written by apache2.

**Important:** Note that doing it this way, anybody who has access to your user account can modify the websites files.

Answer (score 1):

/var/www needs to be readable by the apache user. On my Ubuntu 9.04 apache is running as `www-data`.

Changing the ownership and permissions everything in /var is not a good thing to do and you should put it back as it was.

Comment: Is there a way to reset them?

Comment: @lain: var and www are chowned www-data:deltrem, var is chmoded 711, www 751, it still doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

What user is apache running as? It normally runs as user 'httpd' or 'apache' (iirc), so try chowning /var/www back to that user. You shouldn't chown -r /var - there will be other things what want to read and write there that will probably cause you grief very soon.

Comment: It runs as www-data. I chowned it to www-data, but it still didn't work.